# appending successfully to a python list

Tags: python, list, append, dictionary

This may seem like the worlds simplest python question... But I'm going to give it a go of explaining it.

Basically I have to loop through pages of json results from a query.

the standard result is this

```
{'result': [{result 1}, {result 2}], 'next_page': '2'}
```

I need the loop to continue to loop, appending the list in the result key to a var that can be later accessed and counted the amount of results within the list. However I require it to loop only while next_page exists as after a while when there are no more pages the next_page key is dropped from the dict.

currently i have this

```
next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    try:
        next_page_result = get_results['next_page'] # this gets the next page
        next_url = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json" + next_page_result)# this opens the next page
        json_loop = simplejson.load(next_url) # this puts the results into json
        new_result = result.append(json_loop['results']) # this grabs the result and "should" put it into the list
    except KeyError:
        next_page = False   
        result_count = len(new_result)
```

Comment: Where it says next_page == False it should probably say next_page = False. You're assigning, not checking for equality.

Comment: well spotted.. i've edited that now... thanks for pointing that out

Comment: `foo == True` is spelled `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate (cleaner) approach, making one big list:

```
results = []
res = { "next_page": "magic_token_to_get_first_page" }
while "next_page" in res:
    fp = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json" + res["next_page"])
    res = simplejson.load(fp)
    fp.close()
    results.extend(res["results"])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_result = result.append(json_loop['results'])
```

The list is appended as a side-effect of the method call.
`append()` actually returns `None`, so `new_result` is now a reference to `None`.

Comment: @Neil Hickman:  You don't "work around it.  `result.append` updates result.  It has the new value.  You can say `new_result=result` if you think it help, but `result` is updated by `append`.  There is no return value: a new list is *not* created.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use

```
result.append(json_loop['results']) # this grabs the result and "should" put it into the list
new_result = result
```

if you insist on doing it that way. As Bastien said, `result.append(whatever) == None`

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS, you don't need the variable new_result at all.

```
result_count = len(result)
```

will give you the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot append into a dict..you can append into your list inside your dict,you should do like this

```
result['result'].append(json_loop['results'])
```

if you want to check if there is no next page value in your result dict,and you want to delete the key from the dict,just do like this

```
if not result['next_page']:
    del result['next_page']
```